# Bootstrap 4 Carosuel with ACF Repeater field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Given this HTML code, how can I create a dynamic Carosuel with thumbnails using Bootstrap 4 that can be updated in back-end using ACF Repeater?

My Repeater field is called `carousel_repeater` and inside I have an Image field called `carosuel_image`

HTML code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="custCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" align="center">
                <!-- slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/weXVL8M.jpg" alt="Hills"> </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Rpxx6wU.jpg" alt="Hills"> </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/83fandJ.jpg" alt="Hills"> </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JiQ9Ppv.jpg" alt="Hills"> </div>
                </div> <!-- Left right --> <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#custCarousel" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span> </a> <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#custCarousel" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span> </a> <!-- Thumbnails -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators list-inline">
                    <li class="list-inline-item active"> <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#custCarousel"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/weXVL8M.jpg" class="img-fluid"> </a> </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"> <a id="carousel-selector-1" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#custCarousel"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Rpxx6wU.jpg" class="img-fluid"> </a> </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"> <a id="carousel-selector-2" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#custCarousel"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/83fandJ.jpg" class="img-fluid"> </a> </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"> <a id="carousel-selector-2" data-slide-to="3" data-target="#custCarousel"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JiQ9Ppv.jpg" class="img-fluid"> </a> </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="custCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" align="center">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
<?php
        if( have_rows('carousel_repeater') ):
        
            // Loop through rows.
            while( have_rows('carousel_repeater') ) : the_row();
                $sub_value = get_sub_field('sub_field');// whatever ur image field is called
?>

                    <div class="carousel-item active"> <img src="<?php echo $sub_value['url'] ?>g" alt="Hills"> </div>

       
 <?php
            // End loop.
            endwhile;
?>
                <ol class="carousel-indicators list-inline">
                    <li class="list-inline-item active"> <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#custCarousel"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/weXVL8M.jpg" class="img-fluid"> </a> </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"> <a id="carousel-selector-1" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#custCarousel"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Rpxx6wU.jpg" class="img-fluid"> </a> </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"> <a id="carousel-selector-2" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#custCarousel"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/83fandJ.jpg" class="img-fluid"> </a> </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"> <a id="carousel-selector-2" data-slide-to="3" data-target="#custCarousel"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JiQ9Ppv.jpg" class="img-fluid"> </a> </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php   
    endif; 
    ?>
```

Probs something like this, your gna need to play with it as i havent tested it but this is a start, would recommend you look into the documentation for ACF repeaters

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/